# JS: This algorithm is doing weird thing, (analysis)

Tags: javascript

This code is took from my constructor a tiny part.

The first output should be ('1' or '2') then '0' til the end; Instead of pure '0' only. It gives me 1000 of 0. I don't know why.

I tested with lower values at the 'cols' and 'row' variables, and it works fine. (it outputs: '1' the first time, then '0')But when the cols and rows are higher the problem appears again.
Its for a memory limit? I dont know about how much memory.

What should I do, to avoid this problem in future? Should I use functions? for each or something like recursive? Thank you.

P.N. if you dont seem any problem, try to set higher values to cols and rows. maybe this should trigger the issue.

```js
var i, row_rate
var cols = 50
var rows = 31
var count = 0

for (i = 0; i < cols * rows; i++) {

  row_rate = Math.trunc(Math.trunc(i / cols) * 100 / rows)

  if (count > 0) {
    console.log(0)
  }
  else if (row_rate <= 20) {
    // the first time must pass here...
    count++
    console.log(1)
  }
  else {
    // ...or here
    count++
    console.log(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understnad neither what you are trying to do nor what you expect. Please improve your answer.

Comment: Hi it's very simple ,When I execute the code it outputs 1000 of 0; and that's not correct
What it should output is first time the number '1' then it should output '0' till the end.

Also when I set lower values to `cols` and `rows` variables it works very fine. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `console.log()` is not `0`, but `1`, and after that one thousand of zeros are logged:

[image]

*(the 1549 number means 1549 repeats of the same log line)*

The problem is that the output don't supports that number of lines, so the older ones are removed. On Chrome Developer Tools (F12) you can check `Group similar` to avoid this problem:
[image]

You can see it easily also by `break`ing on the `0` console log. You will see that the first log line is actually `1` before logging the `0`:

```js
var i, row_rate
var cols = 50
var rows = 31
var count = 0

for (i = 0; i < cols * rows; i++) {

  row_rate = Math.trunc(Math.trunc(i / cols) * 100 / rows)

  if (count > 0) {
    console.log(0)
    break;
  }
  else if (row_rate <= 20) {
    // the first time must pass here...
    count++
    console.log(1)
  }
  else {
    // ...or here
    count++
    console.log(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG you have to be joking if the guy confused the output with the similar grouping flag

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde no no, I think that what se says is that when he scrolls the log output to the top, he sees as the first line a 0. I think that he is using windows or putty and the log is being trimmed at the top part. Happens with stackoverflow simulated console.log also.

Comment: `row_rate`isn't always bellow or equal to 20. all the structure depends of `count`, so if that variable is more than 0 it should output only '0'; I add `count++` in the `else if` statement; also Im using firefox, (my windows xp, doens't support chrome).

Comment: `row_rate` is a rows rate, it start from 0% to 100%, (0 to 100, more or less)

Comment: @vincentthorpe Oh yeah, that's true, my fault. Going to edit my answer. Also, I'd like you to accept the answer if it actually replied your question, which I don't understand clearly if that's the problem.